# Is there any way to implement drag and drop sortable Ant Design Collapse?

Tags: drag-and-drop, antd, draggable, sortablejs, dnd-kit

https://ant.design/components/collapse

using Collapse component from Ant.design 5.12
not able to implement vertical drag and drop sortable mechanism as the Collapse.Panel is deprecated now. So there is no children of collapse. All items will be rendered by items props.